# Convert classic asp variable into jquery variable

Tags: jquery, asp-classic

Here is my code.. This is giving me a hard time though I know there is a simple answer

```
var myVAr = '<%=data.name%>';

$(myVAr).insertAfter("#thisDiv");
```

Comment: What is the problem? What happens and what do you expect to happen? What is `data.name`? Your code you posted seems to be correct given that `data.name` exists and has a value that is understandable by jQuery.

Comment: for some reason it just gives me the plain text and not the value or the var

Comment: If you response.write data.name straight onto the HTML page, what do you find?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must call [insertAfter](http://api.jquery.com/insertAfter/) on a jquery object. So you could do:

```
var myVAr = $('<input>',{name :'<%=data.name%>', type: "text"} );

myVAr.insertAfter("#thisDiv");
```

fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/FhUF5/

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the `data.name` does not have a `'` inside it as it will break the javascript string.

And then make sure that the jquery code is executed after the page has loaded

```
var myVAr = '<%=data.name%>';
$(function(){
  $(myVAr).insertAfter("#thisDiv");
});
```

---

If the `data.name` does not represent valid html code, and you just want the `data.name` to be inserted as text after the `#thisDiv` then make a tag with jquery which holds the `data.name`

```
var myVAr = '<%=data.name%>';
$(function(){
  $('<span>',{text:myVAr}).insertAfter("#thisDiv");
});
```